# Error Signing Xamarin.iOs Application { codesign exited with code 3. }

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to Build a xamarin.ios app with VS2019 installed in  windows, connected to macOs added as a remote build server. Everything is ok, but when is trying to verify the signature fails showing this:

```
error : codesign exited with code 3
```

After some debugging we found out that the VS is loging of the dev's portal for some reason.

I'll appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Comment: An exit code of 3 means that codesign failed due to path verification. Review the detailed build log to determine the root cause.

Comment: Hi , you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48575062/xamarin-ios-error-msb6006-codesign-exited-with-code-1) to check whether your problem is similar with it .

Comment: @SushiHangover the build log says that it fails trying to verify the signature

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Nop, there's no relation between that question and mine.

Comment: @tlandaeta Okey , will continue to check what is the reason .

Answer (score 0):

CodeSign encounters issues to verify the signature of your signing certificate, provisioning profile and App. I first ran into this issue when building on MS AppCenter, but was able to reproduce after running the Archive for Publishing command from Visual Studio

Use Terminal to execute codesign with detailed logging on your App by using the following statement:

```
codesign -dv MyApp.app
```

Note: You can drag and drop your MyApp.app from your Finder window into the Terminal app.

Details about your signature will be displayed. In my case "TeamIdentifier=not set" and the "Signature=adhoc" were shown, while I was developing an InHouse app, meaning that the provided Provisioning Profile was generated as Ad Hoc instead of InHouse.