# What causes CoDesign exited with code 1 every other build

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, codesign

On every other build or so i my xamarin ios project fails to build with codesign exited with code 1 being the error. This is immediately fixed by cleaning the solution and waiting the roughly 5 - 10 minutes it takes to rebuild the project from scratch

I have googled this extensively and checked to make sure all my certificates are correct and everything is signing correctly. and I believe I have this confirmed as after a clean solution it builds and deploys perfectly fine to the device i am testing. For now i have a solution to this it is just infuriating having to wait upwards of 10 minutes for each deploy just to have it say CoDesign exited with code 1 and have to clean and rebuild.

Comment: Is there any other error message beside CoDesign exited with code 1? Look at these threads may help: [xamarin-ios-error-msb6006](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48575062/xamarin-ios-error-msb6006-codesign-exited-with-code-1) and [codesign failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023639/xcode-command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1-errsecinternalcomponen)

Comment: Nope the only error i receive is CoDesign exited with code 1, In addition ive tried both manual and automatic provisioning as the first link suggested and both reacted the same where a clean build will deploy but a build that was already built would fail with co design error 1. I locked all my keychains last night and powered down both machines and this morning i am only getting the error rarely with the solution again being clean rebuild. Im not sure why but the power reset atleast seemed to make it rarer...

Comment: Maybe there are some caches in the VS or your mac before you restart them.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue my going into the *AppName*.iOS project properties and on the left sidebar navigate to the "Application" option and change the "Startup object:" to be *AppName*.iOS.Application. As soon as I did that it started working for me.