# Xamarin.ios Error MSB6006: “codesign” exited with code 1 When Trying to Archive for Publishing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am having an error like [Xamarin.ios Error MSB6006: "codesign" exited with code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48575062/xamarin-ios-error-msb6006-codesign-exited-with-code-1) except this is when I am doing "Archive for Publishing" which is a step to publish Xamarin.ios. Can you guys please assist me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

About publishing to App Store :

**First** , need to [Create and install an App Store provisioning profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing-to-the-app-store?tabs=windows#create-and-install-an-app-store-provisioning-profile) .

iOS uses provisioning profiles to control how a particular application build can be deployed. These are files that contain information about the certificate used to sign an app, the App ID, and where the app can be installed. For development and ad hoc distribution, the provisioning profile also includes the list of allowed devices to which you can deploy the app. However, for App Store distribution, only certificate and App ID information are included since the only mechanism for public distribution is the App
Store.

Second, [Update the Release build configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing-to-the-app-store?tabs=windows#update-the-release-build-configuration)

The last , [Build and submit your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing-to-the-app-store?tabs=windows#build-and-submit-your-app) .

Note : If using Automatical Provisioning will see a Team Account there .
[image]

Or Manual Provisioning will select the provisioning file directly  .
[image]