# Xamarin Forms IOS Build - Plutil Exit Compiler Error No Localisation Files Present

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

Upon IOS Debug Build I get a Build Error:
`/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(3,3): Error MSB6006: "plutil" exited with code 1. (MSB6006)`

The Error Directs me to this Line:

```
    <OptimizePropertyList
            SessionId="$(BuildSessionId)"
            Condition="'$(IsMacEnabled)' == 'true'"
            ToolExe="$(PlUtilExe)"
            ToolPath="$(PlUtilPath)"
            Input="%(_PropertyList.Identity)"
            Output="$(DeviceSpecificIntermediateOutputPath)optimized\%(_PropertyList.LogicalName)">
        </OptimizePropertyList>
```

I have come Across and tried the solutions from the following question:
[Xamarin.ios Error MSB6006: "codesign" exited with code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48575062/xamarin-ios-error-msb6006-codesign-exited-with-code-1)

I have Tried:

1. Renewing Certificate
2. Cleaning Solution
3. Bundeling my Info.plist as BundleResource
4. Setting my Link Behaviour

Notes:

1. I have no Localisation File
2. My Info.plist does not have the same options as mentioned in above qeustion please see below screenshot.
3. My XCode is Running And Succeeds on the blank application
4. I am using a Emulated Device

[Screenshot of Info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1YKq.png)

I have scoured Google for different apporaches to resolving the issue but most seem related to localisation strings, Which I do not have in my Solution.

Assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you set the `Custom Commands` in your build options?I found there's a [similar situation](https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-template-creator-addin/issues/2) for your case.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT I have looked at that, I have no Custom Commands set, My only plist  are Entitelement.plist and GoogleServices.plist

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue is related with this plist file `GoogleServices.plist`.You may have a incorrect version of the `GoogleServices.plist`.

Please try to **delete** the plist and **re-download** and **re-add** the plist again.